# sort records in postgres using just a part of string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have several records and one of my field is segment_number and it is as of:

```
PID_1
PID_2
PID_11
PID_14
PID_6
```

I want to sort all the records based on segment_number field but as its is a string and the number is at the end of the string I am not able to sort it in ascending order of numbers.

If I use ORDER BY segment_number,I get the order as this which is not what I want:

```
PID_1
PID_11
PID_14
PID_2
PID_6
```

What I want:

```
PID_1
PID_2
PID_6
PID_11
PID_14
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: You could try ordering by something like right(columnname, len(column name)-4)

Answer (score 2):

It is not common, but you can use functions like `regexp_replace` to extract numbers and sort them.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b61cb7a17e138f3a43b226b35f0dd5af)

```sql
select
  *
from
  test
order by
  regexp_replace(data, '.*_([0-9]+)', '\1')::int;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need *numerical sorting*.

One option would be using `REGEXP_MATCHES()` with `\d+` pattern

```sql
SELECT col
  FROM t
 ORDER BY (REGEXP_MATCHES(col,'\d+'))[1]::INT
```

or `REPLACE()` in order to get rid of the prefix along with integer conversion such as

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t
 ORDER BY REPLACE(col,'PID_','')::INT
```

if the dataset has the same pattern throughout the table

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2baa8beecc2a9043d66c77f7899d3691)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by substring is much simpler than doing it by regex:

```
postgres=# create table test(segment_number varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test values ('PID_1'),('PID_11'),('PID_14'),('PID_2'),('PID_6');
INSERT 0 5

postgres=# select segment_number  from test order by substring(segment_number,5)::int;
 segment_number
----------------
 PID_1
 PID_2
 PID_6
 PID_11
 PID_14
(5 rows)
```